# Create a virtual window for painting in memory only

Tags: winapi, window

I have a win32 screen saver application that gets its device context from the HWND that's passed into `ScreenSaverProc`, using, for instance, `BeginPaint`.

Now I want to use the same code to create a video of the screen saver (ussing `ffmpeg`, but that's not relevant). What I'd like to do is put a wrapper around the code which calls `ScreenSaverProc` (instead of having `libscrsave` do it), and passing in some kind of virtual window, so that it can get the device context the same way as usual and paint on it, but then in the wrapper code I can get at the device context's bitmap and copy it into a frame of the video.

Is there a way to create such a virtual window? Would it work to just create a regular window and leave it hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure the screen saver into a thin wrapper function that just obtains a device context, then calls another function to do the drawing into the DC:

```
void On_WmPaint() { 
    HDC dc = BeginPaint();
    // ...
    do_draw(dc);
    EndPaint();
}

void do_draw(HDC dc) { 
  // ...
}
```

Then when you want to create a frame for your video, you can use CreateCompatibleDC (for one possibility) to create a DC compatible with your screen. Then use CreateCompatibleBitmap to create a bitmap (also compatible with the screen). Select that bitmap into the DC, then call `do_draw`, passing it that DC. That will draw into the bitmap you selected into the DC, so afterwards you can do what you wish with the bitmap.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the standard screensaver interface where I could pass in an `HWND` instead of a specific `HDC`, but this might be a reasonable work around. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: It does work, still not ideal for me, but it might be the only way. If I try to draw to a Window's DC while the window is hidden or obscured, it seems to freeze up. I don't have that issue using the memory DC like you suggest. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Surely--glad to help.